# SQL Joint and Group two tables with SUM function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SO i have two tables:

```
Products
Product ID | Quantity

OrdersLines 
Product ID | Amount (multiple lines with same ID)
```

I want to join two tables. Result should be - Product ID (Group by), Quantity and Sum of all amounts from OrdersLines table.

I got this so far:

```
SELECT P.ProductID, P.Quantity, SUM(OL.Amount)
FROM atbl_Sales_Products AS P
LEFT JOIN atbl_Sales_OrdersLines AS OL ON OL.ProductID = P.ProductID 
GROUP BY P.ProductID
```

This produces error:

> Column 'atbl_Sales_Products.Quantity' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Don't you want to `SUM(P.Quantity)` as well? I wouldn't use a `LEFT JOIN`. Use an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two ways to write this depending on what you want

Adding the Quantity to the aggregate...

```
SELECT 
   P.ProductID, 
   SUM(P.Quantity), 
   SUM(OL.Amount)
FROM atbl_Sales_Products AS P
LEFT JOIN atbl_Sales_OrdersLines AS OL ON OL.ProductID = P.ProductID 
GROUP BY P.ProductID
```

Adding the quantity to the grouping

```
SELECT 
   P.ProductID, 
   P.Quantity, 
   SUM(OL.Amount)
FROM atbl_Sales_Products AS P
LEFT JOIN atbl_Sales_OrdersLines AS OL ON OL.ProductID = P.ProductID 
GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.Quantity
--based on comment
HAVING SUM(OL.Amount) > P.Quantity
```

Comment: second one works for me. One more thing, is there a way to select only these rows where Quantity > SUM(OL.Amount)?

Comment: Sure, but that logic doesn't make much sense to me. You would want to find when there were more products than the total cost of them?

Comment: Products table is like a warehouse (Quantity = Available amount of products). OrdersLines (Amount = currently ordered/reserved amount). I want to select only lines where some amount is still available.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes a bit more sense then. I'll post an edit

Comment: SELECT 
   P.ProductID, 
   P.Quantity, 
   SUM(OL.Amount)
FROM atbl_Sales_Products AS P
LEFT JOIN atbl_Sales_OrdersLines AS OL ON OL.ProductID = P.ProductID 
GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.Quantity
HAVING P.Quantity > SUM(OL.Amount)

Comment: @scsimon: is it possible to have multiple HAVING conditions? For example, this select does not return lines where (OL.Amount is NULL).

Comment: You just need to add that to a WHERE clause, not the HAVING clause